# Trabajar con fracciones en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, bucle-for

¡Buenas! Estoy creando una calculadora super sencilla a través de formularios, no está más que basada en este resolutor de sistemas de ecuaciones propuesto: http://platea.pntic.mec.es/jcarias/mat/algebra/sistemas/01gausshtml.htm

El problema que se me presenta es que al ingresar una fracción del tipo "x/y",el parseFloat que se encuentra en la línea que contiene este ciclo for dentro de la función gauss() me lo reduce a sólo x, eliminando el denominador e invalidando la división:

```
     for(i=1;i<=3;i++){ 

          a[i]=[0,0,0,0],b[i]=[0,0,0,0],c[i]=[0,0,0,0]
      for(j=1;j<=4;j++){ 
          a[i][j]=parseFloat(document.forms[0][4*i+j-5].value) 
      }
    }
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer que las fracciones del tipo "x/y" se resuelvan antes que el parseFloat las recorte, de tal forma que se guarde el decimal de una vez? Entiendo que no debería ser tan difícil, puesto que en la consola probé insertar una fracción tipo "1/2" dentro de un array, y ésta se guardó como decimal de una vez, pero apenas estoy aprendiendo lo muy básico y no me muevo seguro por la programación.

Atento a sus respuestas, y gracias de antemano!

Comment: PD: Cuando me refiero a añadir fracciones del tipo "x/y" me refiero a añadirlas en el campo del formulario, para que sean calculadas.

Comment: Tendrías que *dividir* (`split('/')`) el texto en dos: lo que hay antes de `/` y lo que hay después, hacer un `parseFloat` de cada parte y entonces hacer la división

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Pablo! Al igual que agradecí también a Diego, su sugerencia es exactamente lo que necesitaba, puesto que no sabía cómo utilizar split de forma práctica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseFloat` solo acepta cadenas que representan un número en con decimales (ej. `'3.14'`, `'314e-2'`, `'0.0314E+2'`), no reconoce fracciones.

Lo que puedes hacer buscar el operador `/` en la cadena

```
var str = '3/4';
var operandos = str.split('/'); // esto te devuelve un array ['3', '4']
var resultado = parseInt(operandos[0]) / parseInt(operandos[1]);
```

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!! Es justamente lo que estaba buscando, aunque por si acaso pondré ParseFloat por si a alguien se le ocurriese colocar un numerador y/o denominador como decimal, de resto, justamente necesitaba un ejemplo práctico de cómo utilizar split.

En este momento logré convertirlo en una función que me transforma todas las operaciones fraccionarias en números decimales listos para ser operados, realmente interesante.